# Book series I read sometime in the early 00s set in a fantasy world perhaps on an island with a castle/kingdom nearby

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I checked these books out from my middle school library.  I remember the main characters were a girl and guy.  They were both a sort of unexpected hero.  I know it was set in a fantasy world perhaps on an island with a castle/kingdom nearby.  I believe the bad guy was a magic user.

There were three books in the series at the time, possibly more since.  I only read the first and third, sice somebody misplaced the second one.  They were fairly new books at the time.

When I continued from the first to the third book I remember being a bit shocked that the main characters had gotten married.

The only other things I remember is that they used birds to relay messages, and maybe one of the titles had the word song or swan in it.

I think the cover on one was bright with the protagonists and a bit of the landscape and some bird.

Comment: That's a good start, but go through this guide (https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and see if you can edit in any more information to help people amswer your question.